# ng-model won't update the changed form content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have a form which has a delete entry button and an add entry button. I want to output the updated form field data to `formData={}`, so that the submitted data will be up-to-date. However, when a fieldset is deleted, `formData={}` is not updated with the newest data entry information and the old form data still exist in `formData={}`. [Here's the link for my code](http://codepen.io/fortrustit/pen/ONdmEP?editors=1010)

Comment: sorry guys I have updated the content in Codepen, so the link won't be the original one when I was asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function(){
  var formCtrl = this;
   formCtrl.forms ={
       formData:[{ name:""}]
   };
  
  formCtrl.addFields = function(){
    var name = {name:""};
     formCtrl.forms.formData.splice(formCtrl.forms.formData.length,0,name);
        
    };
  
  formCtrl.rmFields = function(form){
    var index  = formCtrl.forms.formData.indexOf(form);
       formCtrl.forms.formData.splice(index,1);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl as formCtrl">
   <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="form in formCtrl.forms.formData">
        <td> <input type="text" ng-model="form.name"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="formCtrl.addFields()" value="Add" ng-show="$last"></td>
        <td> <input type="button" ng-click="formCtrl.rmFields(form)" value="Delete" ng-show="$index != 0"></td>
     </tr>
   </table> 
    <span>  <pre>{{formCtrl.forms | json }}</pre></span>
</div>
```