# Have a dynamic html element using AngularJS Directive WHITOUT $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controlleras

I want to use [This Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/a7E9sT?p=preview) sample code to add some elements dynamically to HTML page using AngularJS. (*You should run It in a new link, not in editor environment*) This is my first experience in declaring AngularJS Directive (except for simple tests). I have two questions about this sample:

1. My approach is using `Controller as` instead of `$Scope` in my controllers. (I don't know the name of this approach!) So what should I do with the sample code above? since it uses `$compile(...)($scope)`. which changes should be applied?
2. Is the Scope in Directive related to controller? So, If I could omit the scope from controller in this case, should I apply any changes to directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) When use contrller as syntax so for `$compile(...)($scope)` change to `$compile(...)(vm)`. and also for all function and variable instead of $scope use `vm` or `this`

```
var vm = this;
```

so instead of  `$scope.list` use `vm.list` and for function also use.

```
  $scope.do = function() ..

  vm.do = function() ....
```

2) In directive add `controllerAs` like to this

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function () {
   return {
   scope: {},
   controller: function () {
     this.name = 'Elnaz'
   },
   controllerAs: 'ctrl',
   template: '<div>{{ctrl.name}}</div>'
  };
});
```

and if you want to refer to external controller use this

```
   app.directive('myDirective', function () {
     return {
     restrict: 'A',
     controller: 'EmployeeController',
     controllerAs: 'ctrl',
     template: ''
    };
 });
```

in your view change like to this:

```
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
     {{ctrl.name}}

     <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.do()">Do</button>
  </div>
```

Edit:
 [works demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/az1ut50jsTph3tVgaSWm?p=preview)

Comment: thank you so much. But I have some questions:  As you see, there is a controller in directive which has injected the $scope, what should I do with that? is the $scope related to the $scope of Controller? Have you omitted the directive's own controller and myController in directive definition the EmployeeCtrl?

Comment: see this sample may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096954/ng-model-wont-update-the-changed-form-content/37097044#37097044

Comment: Yes I use this approach(controller as) in view. but also I do not understand what should I do with the directive. As you see in plunker sample, the directive has it's own controller and the controllers are needed, both. But as you mentioned above, I can select one of them as controller, and then define a controllerAs for that.

Comment: I created a plunker demo. see https://plnkr.co/edit/az1ut50jsTph3tVgaSWm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Answer for your 1st point:

1. Inside your controller, you would have create one variable which would represent "controller as";

   var vm = this;
2. Now all the properties which was binded to $scope will now be the part of vm
3. In HTML:
       way to bind controller with div : `<div ng-controller="customCntrl as vm"`
4. Now in the view instead of refering scope properties directly, you will have to prefix vm before that like this: vm.name
5. In the directive:
       Way to bind controller with "controller as":

   app.directive('customDir', function() {
                   return {
                     controller: 'customCntrl',
                         controllerAs: 'vm',
                     ...

   ```
               }
           });
   ```

Answer to your 2nd point:

1. You can still apply broadcast and emit over 'vm' like this:

   $scope.$watch('vm.name', function() {
           $scope.$broadcast('topic-123', 'msg');
       });

   And to capture it:
    $scope.$on('topic-123', function(event, msg) {});